# Kali Linux и TP-Link tl-wn725n

Tags: linux, компиляция, wifi, kali-linux

### Дано:

- WiFi адаптер TP-Link *tl-wn725n* на чипсете *rtl8188eu*
- Ноут с виртуалкой **Linux OS 5.4.0-kali2-amd64** (данные предоставила комманда uname -r)
- Кривые руки

### Нужно:

- Перевести данный девайсик в **monitor mode** при помощи утилиты **airmon-ng**

### Проблемы:

Дело в том, что в кастомной прошивке адаптера нет мониториг режима, и я как сыщик начал длительные поиски.
Сначала в GitHub наткнулся на этот [Драйвер](https://github.com/quickreflex/rtl8188eus/tree/30c129990fb7432c8a96571ca9625e6f2911b99f), обрадовавшись кинулся клонировать репозитории.
Загрузилась, перешел в каталог `cd rtl8188eu`. И на этапе `make all` выводит ошибку:

---

```
nappy@nappy:~/rtl8188eus$ make all
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-kali2-amd64/build M=/home/nappy/rtl8188eus  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/5.4.0-kali2-amd64/build: Нет такого файла или каталога.  Останов.
make: *** [Makefile:1911: modules] Ошибка 2
```

---

Не понял, что он хочет, пошел гуглить. Понял, что что-то не так, а что не понял. Какие-то заголовки ядра устанавливать надо, или моя версия не совместима с этой версией драйверов, в общем помогите...
Заранее большое спасибо!

/Абсолютный новичок в среде Linux (можно сказать, что полный ноль), недавно научился открывать и редактировать sources.list/

Comment: надо хедеры для ядра установить.

Comment: А как это сделать и для чего он нужен?

Comment: вот есть пример, как установить - https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-linux-kernel-headers-on-kali-linux-2-0-kali-sana/  Зачем это нужно? потому что чтобы собрать модули ядра, коду нужно знать, с каким ядром оно собирается. Ну почему все, ставят сразу кали линукс, не хотят вначале попробовать нормальный, обычный. Ну не нужен он вам...

Comment: @KoVadim патамушта верят, что, взяв его в руки, немедленно станут кулхацкерами. Ну и вот...

Comment: @kovadim, мне не нужны сайты на который решена другая задача, потому что, я уже все что можно обшарил в поисках достойного ответа

Comment: иногда, что бы увидеть правильный ответ, нужно знать, как он выглядит. Если не знать, то не получится никак.  Но если Вы не можете установить хедеры ядра, тогда ... тогда меняйте дистрибутив или драйвер.